# If a set could be represented as "arbitrary fine" finite union of open balls, then it is not closed

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

If $V$ is a subset of a metric space, such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a finite number of open balls $B_{\varepsilon}(x_i)$ such that
$$
 V = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n B_{\varepsilon}(x_i)
$$
then $V$ could not be closed. I conjecture that this is true, but have no idea how to proof this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not true in general. In fact, [totally bounded metric spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space#Definition_for_a_metric_space) are unions of finitely many arbitrarily fine open balls, but are certainly closed in themselves.

Nor is the whole space the only such counterexample. For instance, consider the subset $X=(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ of $\Bbb R.$ Restricting the usual metric of $\Bbb R$ to $X$ makes $X$ a metric space, both $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$ are unions of finitely many arbitrarily fine open balls, and both are closed in $X$ (though of course, not in $\Bbb R$).

For yet another example, take any infinite set $Y,$ and equip $Y$ with the standard *discrete metric* $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0 & x=y\\1 & x\ne y.\end{cases}$$ Then in fact **every** subset of $Y$ is open (so every subset of $Y$ is closed), since in particular each singleton $\{x\}$ is the open $d$-ball about $x$ of radius $\varepsilon$ for all $0<\varepsilon<1.$ Every *finite* subset of $Y$ then provides an example of a closed subset of $Y$ that is a union of finitely many arbitrarily fine open balls.

Comment: in the article they speak about the whole space, but is it still not true if I consider just proper subsets $V$ of a metric space?

Comment: @Stefan: An open connected component of a metric space is closed.

Comment: @StefanH.: Took the words right out of my mouth.

Comment: @CameronBuie: I'm sorry. But I was going to write that comment anyway, before I had seen Stefan's comment.

Comment: @StefanH.: Not to worry!

Comment: "*both are closed in X (though of course, not in R)*" but I always mean w.r.t. to the given topology, not the subspace topology, I came up with your examples too. but I am unable to find a **proper** subset $V$ of a metric space $X$ having this property which is closed w.r.t. the topology on the whole of $X$.

Comment: @Stefan: But $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$ **are** proper subsets of the metric space $X$ I gave you, and **are** closed with respect to the topology on the whole of $X$. It's true that $X$ happens to be a subspace of the reals with the usual topology, but we aren't considering the reals as the overlying space in this example.

Comment: @Stefan: I've added another example that may be easier for you to accept/follow. See what you think.